# PHP - Display Tags Within Tag as Text

Tags: php, html

Sorry for not being able to make the title clearer.

Basically I can type text onto my page, where all HTML-TAGS are stripped, except from a couple which I've allowed.

What I want though is to be able to type all the tags I want, to be displayed as plain text, but only if they're within 'code' tags. I'm aware I'll probably use htmlentities, but how can I do it to only affect tags within the 'code' tag?

Can it be done?

Thanks in advance guys.

For example I have $_POST['content'] which is what's shown on the web page. And is the variable with all the output I'm having problems with.

Say I post a paragraph of text, it will be echoed out with all tags stripped except for a few, including the 'code' tag.

Within the code tag I put code, such as HTML information, but this should be displayed as text. How can I escape the HTML tags to be displayed as plain text within the 'code' tag only?

Below is an example of what I may type:

```
Hi there, this is some text and this is a picture <img ... />. 
Below I will show you the code how to do this image:

<code>
    <img src="" />
</code>
```

Everything within the  tags should be displayed as plain text so that they won't get removed from PHP's strip_tags, but only html tags within the  tags.

Answer (score 0):

If it's STRICTLY code tags, then it can be done quite easily.

First, explode your string by any occurences of '`' or '`'.
For example, the string:

```
Hello <code> World </code>
```

Should become a 4-item array: {Hello,`,World!,`}

Now loop through the array starting at 0 and incrementing by 4. Each element you hit, run your current script on (to remove all but the allowed tags).
Now loop through the array starting at 2 and incrementing by 4. Each element you hit, just run htmlspecialentities on it.

Implode your array, and now you have a string where anything inside the  tags is completely sanitized and anything outside the  tags is partially sanitized.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that should do the trick:

```
$parsethis = '';
$parsethis .= "Hi there, this is some text and this is a picture <img src='http://www.google.no/images/srpr/logo3w.png' />\n";
$parsethis .= "Below I will show you the code how to do this image:\n";
$parsethis .= "\n";
$parsethis .= "<code>\n";
$parsethis .= "    <img src='http://www.google.no/images/srpr/logo3w.png' />\n";
$parsethis .= "</code>\n";

$pattern = '#(<code[^>]*>(.*?)</code>)#si';

$finalstring = preg_replace_callback($pattern, "handle_code_tag", $parsethis);

echo $finalstring;

function handle_code_tag($matches) {
    $ret = '<pre>';
    $ret .= str_replace(array('<', '>'), array('&lt;', '&gt;'), $matches[2]);
    $ret .= '</pre>';
    return $ret;
}
```

What it does:

First using `preg_replace_callback` I match all code inside `<code></code` sending it to my callback function `handle_code_tag`which escapes all less-than and greater-than tags inside the content. The matches array wil contain full matched string in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpJkt.png) and the match for `(.*?) in [2].`#si` **s** means match . across linebrakes and **i** means caseinsensitive

The rendered output looks like this in my browser:
[image]

Comment: sorry but that's not working, the tags within the <code> is still being removed

Comment: what i'm kinda looking for is the php strip_tags functionality, but to invoke htmlentities on tags within <code></code>

Comment: First, my example code replaces all `<` and `>`'s with `&lt;` and `&gt;`'s inside the `<code> ... </code>`. I thought you wanted to be able to display the actual tags  instead of the rendered version inside `<code`? So you want to completely remove all tags inside `<code>` ending up with only the text inside the tags?

Comment: your code is what i want, but its not working, it still displays < and > instead of &lt; my script strips all tags, but i need it so that the tags within the <code> tags aren't stripped, but displayed as plain text, can it be done?

Comment: Can you update your post with some semi-real data, so I might test it on my server please?

Comment: Your code should work, as you can see in my rendered version of the page

Comment: thanks so much for your help but it doesnt work for me, it doesn't convert the < and > to lt and gt. Either way i've posted a solution I found in my original question. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I'm so sorry! I se the bug now. i assumed there was a clean `<code>` tag, but I can now see that you put more information inside the `<code...>`. I have updated my example now

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found which works perfectly for me.
Thanks everyone for their help!

```
function code_entities($matches) {
    return str_replace($matches[1],htmlentities($matches[1]),$matches[0]);
}

$content = preg_replace_callback('/<code.*?>(.*?)<\/code>/imsu',code_entities, $_POST['content']);
```